# Can I pin docker API version : client version 1.38 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.37

Tags: docker, go, versioning

Is there a way to pin docker API version using the golang client? (short of using [dep for vendoring](https://github.com/golang/dep))

code below fails with

```
client version 1.38 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.37
```

This code ran fine until recently

```
go version go1.9.5 linux/amd64
```

here is :  `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      18.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   f150324
 Built:        Wed May  9 22:16:25 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.05.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   f150324
  Built:        Wed May  9 22:14:32 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

this kicks up the API version mismatch

```
package main

// kill off some containers

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"

    "strings"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewEnvClient()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // <--- crashes here due to API mismatch
    }

    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(ctx, types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, container := range containers {

        if strings.Contains(container.Image, "enduser") || strings.Contains(container.Image, "admin") {

            fmt.Println("\n we found enduser or admin so lets stop it\n")

            fmt.Print("Stopping container ", container.ID[:10], "... ")
            if err := cli.ContainerStop(ctx, container.ID, nil); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Success")
        }
    }
}
```

In English, the above error is because the default client version of the github repo client library is newer than version supported by Docker ... so to address the comment - one approach which works is to request a lower version of the repo library to match Docker, not to request a higher version

Below approach to negotiate also works fine

> cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())

Comment: Just ran into the same issue: `client version 1.40 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.39.` It doesn't make sense to me to set the client version to something higher than the currently supported API version (1.39 as of now): https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and @zero298's answer worked perfectly for me =)

Then I found `client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation()` and that also worked!

If you don't require pinning the version and just want the code to work with whatever version your machine is running, I think this option will suite your needs.

Answer (score 32):

You can ask for a version specifically with [`NewClientWithOpts()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#NewClientWithOpts).

```go
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithVersion("1.37"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

---

See [Versioned API and SDK](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/#versioned-api-and-sdk).  At the tail end it brings up using the Go API and (tries) to link to the relevant code:

> You can specify the API version to use, in one of the following ways:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - ...
> - For the SDKs, you can also specify the API version programmatically, as a parameter to the `client` object. See the [Go
>     constructor](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/client.go#L136)
>     or the [Python SDK documentation for
>     `client`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html).

The docs hard link to a line number on the `master` branch which has probably changed, but the code above should provide you with enough context to understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
ctx := context.Background()
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
cli.NegotiateAPIVersion(ctx)  // this line can negotiate API version
```

[NegotiateAPIVersion](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/client/client.go#L205) of client method can solve this API version mismatch problem.