# How to adaptively match the docker client sdk version

Tags: docker, go

I have a project that needs to manage containers through **docker sdk**, and I use [WithAPIVersionNegotiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57260324/11264544) to reduce the version.

The example is as follows

```
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    ctx := context.Background()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cli.Close()

    cmdStatementExecuteScript := cmdStatement
    optionsCreateExecuteScript := types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
        Cmd:          cmdStatementExecuteScript,
    }

    response, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, containerID, optionsCreateExecuteScript)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

But when I deploy the service on multiple machines, the following error occurs because of the *different docker versions on each machine*.

```
panic: Error response from daemon: client is newer than server (client API version: 1.24, server API version: 1.22)
```

`WithAPIVersionNegotiation` config doesn't seem to be downgraded to the **required version**.

Is there some way to satisfy adaptive all versions by coding? Looking forward to your reply.

> PS: Use `WithAPIVersionNegotiation` to **take effect** when *Error response from daemon: client version 1.42 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.39* appears.

go.mod:

```
    github.com/docker/distribution v2.8.1+incompatible // indirect
    github.com/docker/docker v23.0.4+incompatible
    github.com/docker/go-connections v0.4.0 // indirect
    github.com/docker/go-units v0.5.0 // indirect
```